# RStudio - RMarkdown code not rendering in HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having an issue in RStudio where my code from my rmarkdown file runs in studio, but won't display properly in my knitted HTML. For example, the following code to run a plot runs properly for the sample rmarkdown line, but not my own code. The plot shown in the first image should display without the code in the HTML. However it only shows the code:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
e <- ggplot(crash_by_age, aes(Age,Crashes_Reported, color = Sex))
e + geom_point()
````

The following code is from the sample rmarkdown document. This does display in the HTML as shown in image 3.

````
## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
````

```
Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please specify what exactly is not working e.g. by showing error messages or by describing visual elements which should be present in the HTML but are not.

Comment: I edited the post to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the closing three back ticks on the first chunk, so it was not executed:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "danlooo"
date: "3/21/2022"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Including Plots

```{r echo=FALSE}
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
````

Comment: So I had an issue trying to get the text to display properly in my question. If you look at the image the back ticks were included.

Comment: Ah ok. Then I can not reproduce your error